# QML Tableview display value from selected row

Tags: qt, qml, tableview

I have a tableview and I want to open a dialog box on onPressAndHold on a row and display the value of the cell of the row "orderNumber".
But i get the Error message: **ReferenceError: row is not defined**

```
TableView {
    id: tableviewopenorders
    height: 180
    clip: false
    visible: true

    onPressAndHold: oocanceldialog.open()


    TableViewColumn {
        id: orderNumberColumn
        role: "orderNumber"
        title: "Order Number"
    }

    model: openordersModel
}

ListModel {
    id: openordersModel

    ListElement {
        orderNumber: "1223455"

    }
    ListElement {
        orderNumber: "111111"

    }
}


Dialog {
    id: oocanceldialog
    title: "Cancel confirmation"
    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel
    x: (parent.width - width) / 2
    y: (parent.height - height) / 2
    Label {
        text: openordersModel.get(row).orderNumber

    }

    onAccepted: console.log("Ok clicked")
    onRejected: oocanceldialog.close()
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this language, but intuitively, it looks like there is nothing in your code that would set `row` in the expression `openordersModel.get(row).orderNumber`.  Is that the line causing the error?  Is there an event handler for clicking on individual rows vs clicking on the table itself?  Maybe try looking for something like that?

Comment: yes thats the line causing the error. For example when i replace the `onPressAndHold: oocanceldialog.open()` with `onPressAndHold:console.log(openordersModel.get(row).orderNumber)` the I got the correct output printed when i press and hold on the first row i got the 1223455 and when i press and hold on the second row then i got 111111 printed.. But this line is not working when its outside the tableview context

Comment: I wonder how do you think the dialog will get the row. Add `property int row` to the dialog and so set it from pressandhold handler before opening that.

Comment: No, no ... try mine :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row` exists in the context of `onPressAndHold`, so it does not exist outside of it, to get the row we must use the [`currentRow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#currentRow-prop) attribute of the `TableView`:

> **currentRow : int**
>
> The current row index of the view. The default value is -1 to indicate that no row is selected.

In your case:

```
Label {
    text: openordersModel.get(tableviewopenorders.currentRow).orderNumber
}
```